# Draw perfectly centered grid or a cross (for a <div>)?

Tags: css

Sometimes I want to align elements within a div to be centered either horizontally or vertically (without actually writing the code to center them) and obviously the designers have grids in their apps that help them to do that.

Is it possible to create something like that in a css to draw a grid or maybe a simple cross for a specific div, so that it's then much easier to move around elements within that div (because those lines would be a guide to me of how centered that element is)?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method: Create a huge square image with a cross in the middle. Then you can use that image as a centered background:

[image: large cross image]

```css
#some-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 270px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

#some-div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHV0i.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="some-div"></div>
```

Or, you can do it with CSS by using `:before` and `:after`, though, messing up with the element this much may not be possible in some cases:

https://jsfiddle.net/atesgoral/qkomLpo7/

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="stackOvExample">Your content</div>
```

And in the CSS:

```
.stackOvExample{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Not all of my elements need to be centered. I would say I have around 25 and 5 will be vertically centered and another 5 horizontally centered and other 15 conveniently in other places. So I'm rather just looking for a way to help me visually arrange them around (like designers that have the grid that they can show and hide when they arrange stuff around).

Comment: Are you building a layout?